# Working for uk client from abroad

Tags: taxes, uk, group-freelancing

I am thinking of freelancing from a non-EU country for UK clients.
I'll be using my tax ID from that foreign country to invoice UK clients.

I'd like to move to a EU country and freelance from there for UK clients.

This means I will be sending invoices to the client from EU. Because I'm new to the freelancing thing I wanted to know if it makes any different to the client whether I am based in the UK or not  - i.e., do they need to file any taxes or do anything for someone who is invoicing them from EU for a remote freelance gig?

Does it cause any sort of burden for the client to hire an EU freelancer VS a UK based freelancer?

Is there a way I can use my UK home address in the invoice? Will the client need to know if I'm based in UK or abroad?

Comment: How would you plan on getting paid? I believe most clients want to know where you're based if they're spending company money on something...

Comment: This is unclear to me. "Non-EU country for UK clients" then "my UK home". So where you *actually* reside and pay tax is exceptionally ambiguous. (I realize the UK is no longer part of the EU and that may be adding to the confusion.) If you are working for UK clients and reside in the UK... Nothing in the question seems to lean towards "abroad"... so, well.. clarity wouldn't hurt.